# modifying java socket client/server code to print the input of the user and vice versa

Tags: java, sockets

GreetingClient code:

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class GreetingClient
    {
       public static void main(String [] args)
       {
          String serverName = args[0];
          int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
          try{
             System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
             Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
             System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
             OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
             DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
             out.writeUTF("Hello from "+ client.getLocalSocketAddress());
             InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
             DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
             System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
             client.close();
          }
          catch(IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    }
```

GreetingServer code

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class GreetingServer extends Thread{
       private ServerSocket serverSocket;

       public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException{
          serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
          serverSocket.setSoTimeout(6000000);
       }

       public void run(){
          while(true){
             try{
                System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
                Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Just connected to "+ server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                System.out.println(in.readUTF());
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
                out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to " + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");
                server.close();
             }
             catch(SocketTimeoutException s){
                System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                break;
             }
             catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
             }
          }
       }
       public static void main(String [] args){
          int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
          try{
             Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
             t.start();
          }
          catch(IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    }


 //here is the code i want to insert in the client part. this code lets the user type a string (that i want to let it appear on the server side) and asks the user if he want to communicate with the server again.
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class com {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = null;
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean yes = true;
        do{
            System.out.println("What do you want to say to the server?");
            String toServer = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println ("The client said: " + toServer);
            System.out.println("Do you wish to continue(y/n)?");
            try {
                s = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              if(s.equals("n")){
                  yes=false;
              }
        }
        while (yes== true);
    }
}
```

the code works perfectly but not as i want.first i want to include to include the above code(before the last comments) in the greeting user.   i want to make a client server communication.  i have copied and pasted the GreetingServer and GreetingClient part. but once the connection is established between the client and server, the Strings from the GreetingServer and GreetingClient codes appear. that is not what i want. i want to output the user's input from the GreetingClient to the GreetingServer.
the user's input: hi server
On the server should appear : hi server

Comment: What is your question? It is not clear what you are asking. Does the code not work? Is there an exception or error message? Can you [edit] your post and include the stack trace?

Comment: This code is taken directly from [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm) without attribution. That is a violation of the StackOverflow policy against plagiarism. Please read [the Stack Exchange FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do) and follow it. And please ask questions on StackOverflow about *your own code*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a UDP example for you to follow. Should be simple to implement the same approach in your own code.

UdpServer

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class UdpServer {
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 9876;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(SERVER_PORT);
            while(true) {
                byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
                byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                String input = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                input = input.trim();
                System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + input);
                InetAddress ipAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                String capitalizedInput = input.toUpperCase();
                sendData = capitalizedInput.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, ipAddress, port);
                serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

UdpClient

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class UdpClient {
    private static final String CLIENT_IP = "localhost";
    private static final int CLIENT_PORT = 9876;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            while (true) {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(CLIENT_IP);
                String input = bufferedReader.readLine();
                byte[] sendData = input.getBytes();
                byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, ipAddress, CLIENT_PORT);
                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                String modifiedInput = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                modifiedInput = modifiedInput.trim();
                System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedInput);
                clientSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your original code? If it isn't you need to give proper attribution.

Comment: I wrote this code.

Comment: I'm not really sure, but it has some significant similarities (e.g. variable names, exact all cap strings which are printed, port number used) with https://www.mtholyoke.edu/courses/srollins/cs325-f05/web/code/UDPClient.java, which is originally from http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0132856204/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0132856204&linkCode=as2&tag=systembash-20&linkId=ZFUIZQW2DOLTUENY (Your version clearly fixed some of the "odd" things in that version I linked to though). It seems likely to me that it was derived from this.

Comment: There are MANY such samples on the internet. I may have drawn from one such article WAY back in the past, but I wrote this code myself to achieve my own requirements to pass data to and from client and server with some manipulation on the server side. The naming of variables are pretty obvious and would be commonly used by anyone doing the same thing with UDP under the Java coding standards constraints. Welcome to the world of coding :-p